# Retain UILabel value between random views

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, label, uilabel

I'm making a view based quiz app for the iPhone where the player is going randomly between three different views when answering the questions. They get +1 when answering correct and -1 when tapping the wrong answer. But after answering the question, when you go to the new random view, I need the UILabel to show the score from the previous view. How do I do that?

Here is my code:

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *labelQuestion;
IBOutlet UILabel *labelAnswer1;
IBOutlet UILabel *labelAnswer2;
IBOutlet UILabel *labelAnswer3;
IBOutlet UILabel *labelScore;

int score;
```

}

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *labelScore;
@property (nonatomic) int score;


ViewController.m

@synthesize labelScore;
@synthesize score;

-(IBAction)CorrectAnswer; {

    score = score +1;
    labelScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];

}

-(IBAction)WrongAnswer; {

    score = score -1;
    labelScore.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", score];

}
```

Comment: Do you want to persist the score between app launches, or just while the app is running?

Comment: Just when the app is running.

Comment: How do you solve this problem? I look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the variable score global i.e. define this in your `AppDelegate` and you can access it throughout your application.

Comment: Sorry to be a noob, but how do you do that?

Comment: http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/04/04/iphone-accessing-the-global-variables-in-the-appdelegate/

Comment: First, we define our variable in AppDelegate. Then, the classes in which we want to access that variable, first we create an instance of AppDelegate and than we access our variable through that instance. That variable will retain it's value throughout the application.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit further? It sounds like the solution I'm after. Say I have a label in AppDelegate that I want in three other views. My score label is named labelPoang and my three views are named FragaViewController, Fraga2ViewController and Fraga3ViewController. Do I have to add code in both the H and M files for the AppDelegate and the three views? I really appreciate your help. Do I need to set properties for the label.

Comment: You have to add labels in their respective views... but the score variable that you want to display in these 3 labels needs to be defined in AppDelegate. In viewdidload create instance of appDelegate app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; now access app.score whereever you want.

Comment: Hello Smriti. Can you write some code examples to explain this? I look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: @Mattias let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2913/discussion-between-smriti-yadav-and-mattias)

Answer (score 1):

the quickest but dirty way is to store it in app delegate.. and if you want it to persist between app launches, store it in user defaults..
but as i said this is dirty..

Answer (score 1):

As they're properties, when you create the next view you can set the label's text to the current view's text and the score to the current view's.